# What would happen if we ignited one of the gas giants?

Tags: combustion, gas-giant

Since we have the technology to launch an enormous explosive into the atmospheres of the gas giants, would it be possible to light one on fire since their atmospheres are pretty much all just hydrogen and helium? Would it stay burning?

Comment: helium burns at all? hydrogen would burn with what oxidizer?

Comment: To light a hydrogen fire you need oxygen. But our technology may cause only very tiny explosions in a gas giant.

Comment: What seems an enormous explosive to us barely registers to a gas giant.

Comment: Do you mean ignite **nuclear fusion** ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fusion

Comment: I think this question is a good one. Answers should highlight mistakes in the premises. Preconceived ideas can thus be addressed.

Comment: Thank you all for the clarifying comments. It's the oxidization I did not understand. The comment by @Cornelisinspace prompted me to search the question of igniting nuclear fusion and came across [this helpful article](https://www.sciencefocus.com/space/is-it-possible-for-a-gas-giant-like-jupiter-to-ignite/) in case anyone is interested.

Comment: On Earth hydrogen bombs are ignited by nuclear *fission*. The core of Jupiter seems to be metallic hydrogen, i think a nuclear bomb at the core could trigger an explosion that could cause nuclear *fusion* !

Comment: @Cornelisinspace: Hydrogen bombs fuse deuterium and tritium, and gas giants have little of the former and essentially none of the latter. The extreme conditions at the center of the sun can only cause very slow fusion in plain hydrogen-1...volumetrically, the heat output is similar to a compost heap. Even the largest supergiants take millions of years to burn their hydrogen, no mere nuclear bomb in a gas giant core is going to ignite it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combustion requires a fuel (hydrogen), an ignition source (your enormous explosive), and [*an oxidizer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxidizing_agent).

There's a very small amount of oxygen in the atmospheres of the gas giants, almost all of it already bound up in water -- i.e. all the oxygen has already combusted with some of the hydrogen. Without the introduction of a lot more oxygen or other oxidizer, there's no way for the surplus hydrogen to burn.

Comment: Was once some Sci-Fi murder mystery where somebody tried to murder somebody else by sprinkling a catalyst on the regulator of a methane bottle, hoping to spark an explosion. The sleuth's breakthrough clue was the discovery of the same catalyst on an oxygen regulator as well. "Ah Ha!" says the sleuth, "The would-be murderer must be somebody who is used to working out on the surface in the methane atmosphere. He sprinkled the wrong regulator at first, because out there, _oxygen_ is the gas that he must be more careful with."

Comment: @SolomonSlow: I have read that story!

Comment: @SolomonSlow Isaac Asimov, "The Dust of Death" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dust_of_Death